coconut coin(ccc) losted after swap in jupiter
Jupiter tried swapping parclcoins for coconut chiken (ccc), but ccccoins were automatically burned after the swap was completed. The number of ccccoins is not reflected in the phantom wallet, so please solve it.

can you share a transaction signature ?
